# Using XCode for building, profiling, editing unix\linux console programs

Tags: c, linux, xcode, macos

Can you, please, give some pointers for building, profiling and editing C/C++ unix/linux console  programs in XCode.

I could not find any recent HOWTOs on the topic.

Seems that for XCode projects is a must. So I have created new project with "external build system" and added my *.c and *.h files via drag'n'drop.

But I could not "attach to process" from there, because menu item is grayed.

Also, code completing and code jumping does not work, even though definition of structure is in the same file.

*The question is about building/profiling/editing existing C/C++ programs, not creating new ones.*

For example this person is using XCode for MySQL development: http://dom.as/2011/09/25/blowing-up-in-memory/

Comment: There is a simple solution - read about bash, gdb, emacs... and go ahead. Telling you, after a while you will be using these tools even on Mac instead of Xcode :)

Comment: I am using bash, gdb and vim (gvim) right now on Linux. But I would like to try XCode utilities for profiling, etc... Look at http://dom.as/2011/09/25/blowing-up-in-memory/

Comment: You cannot use Xcode profiler to profile applications built for non-supported platforms / architectures like Linux. On the other hand, there is absolutely nothing in Xcode that you cannot do with Intel's Amplifier (vTune). Well, or build your application on OS X and profile it there, but that won't make much sense either as behavior would be a lot different (i.e. epoll vs kqueue etc). Just do not use valgrind :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the code completing, code jumping, etc, you need to create a build target for the utility.  I've been using Xcode for years to develop CLI utilities which I then port to other *nix platforms.

Here are the basic instructions for creating a build target which will allow you to make full use of the Xcode environment when working on your utility:

1. Create an empty project.
2. Add a target using the "Command Line Tool" template (Menubar -> File -> New -> New Target).
3. Delete the files added by the template (usually will be the name of the target).
4. Add the source code to your Xcode project.
5. Open the build phases for the target you created:

   1. Click on the project name in the navigator.
   2. Select your target from the center panel.
   3. Click on the "Build Phases" tab.
6. Under "Compile Sources" added the sources required to build your utility.
7. Under "Link Binary With Libraries" add the required libraries to link your utility.

You may need to add a scheme for your new target, if so:

1. Open the scheme manager (Menubar -> Product -> Manage Schemes).
2. Click on the "Autocreate Schemes Now" button.

You should now be able to use the same tools to build/profile/edit your utility as you would for an OS X or iOS application.

Here are a few examples where I have done the above:

- https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts (has Xcode projects for OpenSSL, OpenLDAP, Cyrus SASL, and PCRE, granted they are currently compiling for iOS).
- https://github.com/bindle/odbcshell (project I wrote for Linux/FreeBSD systems using Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) is an Apple thing and you don't have it on Linux (and I'm not sure that using it in a cross-compiler setting -host being an Apple, target being a Linux- is a good way to work, and it probably is not possible).

On Linux, you could use traditionnal tools (like a mix of Emacs, Make, GCC, ... which is the way Unix people work), or you could try some fancy [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)  like [anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/), [netbeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netbeans), [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and many many others.

I am old enough to find IDE nearly useless for me, and I am very happy using my mixture of Emacs, Make, GCC, Svn or Git, Gdb, etc. I know many experimented Linux developers not using IDEs.

Comment: Yes, but using the analyzer in Xcode is very convenient, even when working on CLI utilities to be ported to other systems.  It might not catch platform specific problems, but will catch problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I used Xcode to write many C and C++ console programs when I was in school. I started each with the Xcode console app template. I depended upon standard C libraries and POSIX. I stayed away from Apple specific libraries. I could build, run, profile, and debug the programs from within Xcode. The only thing I couldn't do within Xcode was produce a portable build configuration. For these class project console programs I would just hand write a makefile for each project. Since I knew from the start that I'd need a hand written makefile, I kept the build process simple.

Now I write mostly iOS apps, but I occasionally write a console app to preprocess data for my iOS apps. I don't see any improvement in newer versions of Xcode for building cross platform build systems. Xcode is focused on iOS and Mac apps, but concedes the need for console programs and includes some Mac OS X specific support.

So my advice for writing console programs for other platforms in Xcode is to keep the build process simple. Start with the Xcode console app project template. Stay with the Xcode project build systems. Make the program work using the Xcode IDE features. Then port the build process to the external build system. Write a makefile, or use whatever build tools you prefer. Use the command line on Mac OS X to build and test the program on Mac OS X from this new build system. Then move the project to another platform and build and test again. I rarely found any problems when I got as far as the second platform.

I even used this method working on teams where my team members were not on Macs. We each used our own choice in build systems, sharing the source code files. Yet, I could see maintaining multiple build systems for large complex programs would quickly become untenable. At which point I would recommend standardizing on one IDE.